# Set header on Axios

Tags: javascript, post, axios

I'm trying to POST on an API but Axios.post keeps failing, while XHR works. I know I have to set the request's headers with UTF-8 but it seems Axios is not recognizing it.

I know I need to set 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' on my header request for this is API was made in Flask and the owner did not configure this part of it. (And because it works with XHR).

The code working is:

```
const post = (url, params) => {
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url, true);

    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    http.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }

    http.send(params);
};
```

So I googled to know how translante #setRequestHeader to Axios.post() and found these links: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/858 and https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/827.

Then I tried something like this:

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
};

const post = ({ data, endpoint }) => axios
    .post(endpoint, data, { headers })
    .then(request => request.data);
```

This:

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
};

const post = ({ data, endpoint }) => axios
    .post(endpoint, data, headers)
    .then(request => request.data);
```

And this:

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
};

const post = ({ data, endpoint }) => axios({
    method: "post",
    url: endpoint,
    data,
    headers
}).then(request => request.data);
```

But every single one of then failed with an error 400.
So, how should I translate http.setRequestHeader() to Axios?

Comment: The problem is probably your `data`. What is it, exactly?

Comment: are you using interceptors ? You might want to take a look to [this bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362)

Comment: FYI, your first attempt is the closest to being correct as you need to put the headers under the `headers` key

Comment: Hi, @Phil. data is an object like this: { text: "this is a text" }.

Comment: That's what I suspected. See the linked duplicate question. Also see the Axios docs ~ https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

From https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/858

```
const endpoint = 'http://localhost/test.php'; // eg.

axios.post(endpoint,
  querystring.stringify({
        paramter: 'value',          
}),
  {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
  });
```

Comment: There's nothing here to serilaize your `{ firstName: this.name }` object to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so this will not work

Comment: You're correct, I will change the answer. Thank's!